# confused about babel australian/british/american hyphenation differences

Tags: babel, hyphenation, english

I'm quite confused about hyphenation differences between the different English variants.

I tend to use `australian` as my default language, but I notice that this often does quite poorly at hyphenation.

There's also differences depending on whether other English variants are loaded and which is the main language.

In the following example:

- Why does Australian English not hyphenate at all?

I'd expect Australian English always to follow British English.

- So perhaps my question is really "How can I make `australian` use British hyphenation patterns?

```
%! TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[en-AU,main,language=Default]{australian}
\babelprovide[en-US,language=Default]{american}
\babelprovide[en-GB,language=Default]{british}

\babelfont{sf}[%
    Numbers = Proportional
  ]{Source Sans Pro}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{parskip}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\textwidth}{333.6463pt}

\newcommand*{\fillertext}{%
  \textsuperscript{5}The \textsc{Lord} saw how great the wickedness of the human
  race had become on the earth, and that every inclination of the thoughts of
  the human heart was only evil all the time. \textsuperscript{6}The
  \textsc{Lord} regretted that he had made human beings on the earth, and his
  heart was deeply troubled.}  

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\hsize}{161.82315pt}

\section{Australian}

\selectlanguage{english}

\fillertext

\section{British}

\selectlanguage{british}

\fillertext

\section{American}

\selectlanguage{american}

\fillertext

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Either remove the tags (`american`, `british`, and `australian` load by default these locales), or add `import=` before them. Anyway, you can change the hyphenation rules with `hyphenrules=`.

Comment: @JavierBezos, thanks. Don't know how I missed the `import`. I notice that `australian` (and all other language variants) use `english` for its hyphenation rules, which is different to both `british` and `american`. Is this just because no one is quite sure for these, so they are left as default?

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in the settings for en-NZ and en-AU. In a few days I’ll release a new version.